# Apps Script to Delete Row from Google Sheet if Match with Cell Value?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working for my script to delete any rows in the POHistory tab of my Google Sheet file that have a matching value in their first cell when compared to the value found in Cell E9 of my POTemplate tab. I am not seeing any response when executing the command, though.  Not sure what is missing here.  I, essentially, am getting an error message stating the rows I am trying to delete are "out of bounds".  Thank you for looking.

```
function deleteOld() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var orderSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("POTemplate");
  var historySheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("POHistory");
  var poNO = orderSheet.getRange("E9").getValue();
  var lastRow = historySheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = historySheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow); 
  var data = myRange.getValues();
 for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
   if(data[i][0] != poNO){
   continue;
   }else{
  historySheet.deleteRow(i);
 }}}
```

Comment: You haven't tried debugging your script, or else you would have noticed that **1)** `data[i]` is an array of values, which can never ever equal a number, and **2)** Deleting rows while advancing forward will lead to deletion of the wrong row after the first deletion.

Comment: Consider catching the exception and logging the values of `i` and the current arrays you are working with. That is a fundamental debugging task associated with out of range errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're deleting a row, the `i` value no longer corresponds to the same range. For example, you have an array with 5 elements:

```
[A, B, C, D, E]
```

If you delete element `0`, you'll get

```
[B, C, D, E]
```

Now you increment your iterator so `i++; // i = 1` and so the next value that you'll operate on is not "B", but instead "C".

You can try yourself by running

```
function test() {
  var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
  for (var i=0; i<letters.length; i++) {
    Logger.log("i : " + i + " || Letter: " + letters[i]);
    letters.shift();
  }
}
```

To fix your code, add a `row` variable that is independent of your array iterator `i`.

Try this as a template:

```
function deleteOld() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var orderSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("POTemplate");
  var historySheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("POHistory");
  var poNO = orderSheet.getRange("E9").getValue();
  var lastRow = historySheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = historySheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow); 
  var data = myRange.getValues();
  var row = 1;
  for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][0] != poNO){
      row++; // Go to the next row
      continue;
    } else {
      historySheet.deleteRow(row);
      row--; // Deleted a row
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your explanation was extremely necessary and very informative.  Thank you, Diego!  Works perfectly!